# Backtrack panels issue

Tags: kde, desktop-environment

I accidentally hid the bottom panel and created another panel on the right side of the screen. That panel is on top of the button to show the bottom panel again. The panel on the right is unclickable and I can't figure out how to delete it.

Is there some config file I can edit to delete that panel?
Can I reset my desktop to default settings?

Comment: You can't move it or right-click on it?

Comment: nope i cant do anything to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the panel settings by deleting `~/.kde4/share/config/plasma-desktop-appletsrc`. I have tried moving the panel and deleting the file does restore the default settings.

If that doesn't work you can try looking for the correct config file and delete it. Well-behaved applications should recreate the file with default settings.

If you don't mind losing customized settings, a sure-to-work way is to remove the KDE settings folder `~/.kde`.